# Qwiic BME280 pressure reading too high?

Tags: python-3.x, sensors, sparkfun

I'm using sparkfun BME280 sensor to collect atmospheric data. temperature & humidity readings are correct but pressure reading is too high. I used another sensor for getting pressure which returns normal reading like 1000hpa while BME280 returns 1180hpa. it's too high. I am using python library and set the pressure_oversample value according to the example written on document(https://qwiic-bme280-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ex4.html) but still getting high value. how can I get correct pressure reading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is relevant in your case, but the Adafruit BME280 library has an adjustment for your location's pressure at sea level:

> bme280.sea_level_pressure = 1013.25

Comment: Thank you. actually I already solved it by using Adafruit BME280 library.